# Why the values of my table is removed when I receive an ActionMessage?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

In my application users need to be able to add products to their basket. I have a page to show a description of the product once the user clicks on `Add` button it should be added to his basket, and if everything goes fine, it shows a confirmation message otherwise shows an error message.

The problem is that, my application shows the messages correctly, but when the message has been shown the product description was removed.

```
<table>
     <tbody>
        <tr><td>ID:${product.ID}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name:${product.name}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price:${product.price}</td></tr>
         ......

         <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
             <s:actionmessage/>
         </s:if>

         <s:form method="GET" action="add">
             <input type="hidden" name="productID" value="${prodcut.ID}"/>
         <s:submit value="Add"></s:submit>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result:**

```
ID: 123
Name: Product1
Price: $12.2

ADD
```

once `Add` button is clicked and product is added to basket

```
ID:
Name:
Price:
      Product is successfully added                 
ADD
```

I know I can use Ajax and JavaScript, but how to show the server message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JSP because you show the product details from the request that is different that used when you added the product. The basket is a kind of object that you should keep in the session and clear when the product is processed. But before clean up you should add messages containing the product details copied from the basket to the request and forward to your JSP. If you redirect to the other action or JSP the request attributes will be lost. In this case if you really need to redirect better put the details in the session. But it should not be a basket object.